# Is there any benefit to using std::string::size_type over size_t?

Tags: c++, stl, size-type

I'm reviewing another developer's code, which contains the following:

```
std::string name;
...
std::string::size_type colon = name.find(":");
```

I'm arguing that using `size_t` would be easier to understand and just as safe, since the STL standard states that `std::string` is `std::basic_string<char, std::allocator>`, and `std::allocator::size_type` is `size_t`.

He wants assurance that that the STL standard couldn't possibly ever change to make this assumption invalid; if the standard could change, then `size_type` would be safer than `size_t`.

Could that happen? Is there any other reason to use `size_type` rather than `size_t`?

Comment: `size_type` fits every container, regardless of what type they use, so it is more consistent.

Comment: You may assume that `name` will always be a real `std::string`.

Comment: There is no "STL standard". The C++ standard could change, but then you'd be in a different language (call it, say "C++11") which is not entirely backward compatible with the language you're using right now (call that, say, "C++03"). Porting code from C++03 to C++11 requires knowing what the breaking changes are, and accounting for them. So you can cross that bridge if you ever come to it. Until then, if the standard says it's true, then it's true. IMO the standard is unlikely ever to change in a way that breaks code using `size_t` for the size of `string` or `vector` with default allocator.

Comment: ... you could as well speculate that a future standard might change the return type of `find` to something other than `std::string::size_type`. There's no accounting for breaking changes.

Comment: @SteveJessop - Your second point is, I think, particularly relevant. Yes, `string::size_type` could change, but so could `string::find()`. Very good point, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`size_type` should be used in code templated on the container type. When the code you have always operates on `std::string`, you can just use `size_t`.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way would be to use `auto` and that way you can automatically conform to whatever the function returns:

```
auto colon = name.find(":");
```

It avoids the problem you're describing and it's a lot shorter.

As larsmans mentions in the comments, you may be wanting to store string indices in a `struct` or whatever without having a variable available to get the return type from. That's doable too:

```
struct StoreStringIndex {
    decltype(declval<std::string>().length()) length;
};
```

But more complicated and not shorter than `std::string::size_type` though. So for storing things, you probably would want to use the type's `size_type`, but for local variables and stuff, use `auto`.

Comment: Nice solution, but you are sidestepping the problem somewhat; suppose you want to store string indices in a `struct` or `class`.

Comment: Or presumably, `decltype(declval<std::string>().find(":")) posn_of_colon;`? I wonder if C++ is the wrong language to be really hardcore about inferring every type, except of course in template code where you can't avoid it.

Comment: @SteveJessop `find` and `length` have the same return type don't they? Then you don't need to put `find(":")` in there.

Comment: Yes they do (according to the standard), and (according to the standard) that type is `size_t`, so you could just as well use that. None of them is wrong, but since you're inferring the type, I would have thought that you'd want to infer it from an expression that relates to its use, rather than from some other expression that just so happens to have the same type. So, from `length()` if the member is used to store a length, and from `find()` if it's used to store an "index or `npos`" resulting from a find.

Comment: Ok, +1. I didn't know about `declval`.

Comment: Woah, magic. Don't think that'd get past the current coding standards here, though! Out of interest, how does `auto` interact with function arguments? Presumably, the derived `auto` type must match the declared type on the function, which rather lessens the usefulness of the `auto`?

Comment: @Chowlett sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by "interact with function arguments".

Comment: Suppose I subsequently need to pass `colon` into another function. That function's arguments must be of well-defined types, yes? And strong-typing will complain if `colon` is the wrong type. So I must have a pretty good idea what `auto`'s going to resolve to - I know `colon` needs to be at least implicitly convertible to the parameter type of the function?

Comment: @Chowlett yes, but that's the same as if you actually specified the type instead of using `auto`. You won't be able to tell a difference, and there are no cases that would work without `auto` that wouldn't work with `auto`.

Comment: No, that's fine (and I was just checking my understanding). It just rather limits the use cases of `auto` to variables local to the current scope; if they're going to be passed on, you've got to work out the type yourself anyway.

Comment: @Chowlett kinda, it's not that big a deal though. If you know that `f(g())` will work, then you know that `auto a = g(); f(a);` will work. You don't have to know the types exactly.