# C++: <= conflict between signed and unsigned

Tags: c++, substring, substr

I have created a wrapper around the .substr function:

```
wstring MidEx(wstring u, long uStartBased1, long uLenBased1)
{
    //Extracts a substring. It is fail-safe. In case we read beyond the string, it will just read as much as it has
    // For example when we read from the word HELLO , and we read from position 4, len 5000, it will just return LO
    if (uStartBased1 > 0)
    {
       if (uStartBased1 <= u.size())
        {
            return u.substr(uStartBased1-1, uLenBased1);
        }
    }
    return wstring(L"");
}
```

It works fine, however the compiler gives me the warning "<= Conflict between signed and unsigned".

Can somebody tell me how to do it correctly?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Change `long` to `unsigned long`?

Comment: Making indices one based is ugly: "u.substr(uStartBased1-1, uLenBased1);"

Comment: You should take the `wstring` as reference to avoid unnecessary copy: `wstring MidEx(const wstring &u, long uStartBased1, long uLenBased1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `wstring::size_type` (or `size_t`) instead of `long`:

```
wstring MidEx(wstring u, wstring::size_type uStartBased1, wstring::size_type uLenBased1)
{
    //Extracts a substring. It is fail-safe. In case we read beyond the string, it will just read as much as it has
    // For example when we read from the word HELLO , and we read from position 4, len 5000, it will just return LO
    if (uStartBased1 > 0)
    {
       if (uStartBased1 <= u.size())
        {
            return u.substr(uStartBased1-1, uLenBased1);
        }
    }
    return wstring(L"");
}
```

which is the exact return type of `u.size()`. This way, you ensure that the comparision gives the expected result.

If you are working with `std::wstring` or another standard library container (like `std::vector`  etc.), then `x::size_type` will be defined as `size_t`. So using it will be more consistent.

Comment: Can you tell me what "size_t" resolves to? I guess it lets the compiler guess which type of variable is required, right?

Comment: `size_t` is the type returned by the `sizeof` operator and, in general, of all functions that will return a size in C. Usually, it is a `typedef` for `usigned long` or `unsigned int`.. See my edit and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10520058) for a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You want `unsigned` arguments, something like:

```
wstring MidEx(wstring u, unsigned long uStartBased1, unsigned long uLenBased1)
```